# Count siblings of a variable in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to perform a simple xpath but coudnt manage to do it..
I create a variable in xsl file as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="list_of_rules">
            <rules>s</rules>
            <rules>np</rules>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I try to perform something like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::$list_of_rules/rules[. = 'np'])"></xsl:value-of>
```

This is not working obviously but all i want to do is count the preceding sibling in list_of_rules variable with given text. I cannot create this list_of_rules variable as i dont have apermission to update xml or xsd files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to invert your thinking. Use the following expression:

```
count($list_of_rules/rules[.='np']/preceding-sibling::*)
```